# How to extract data from axios promisvalue

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying use a weather api to get data but I'm receiving Promisevalue in my console and I couldn't find a way to extract data. my code:

```js
const FetchWeather = async (query) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(URL, {
    params: {
      city: query,
      key: API_KEY,
    },
  });
  return data;
};
```

and I'm getting this response in the console:
[[[PromiseValue]]: Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNozU.png)

Comment: Please check my answer.  You basically have to use "then"

Answer (score 0):

You can use .then(your function goes here.).

This is not an axios thing... This is a javascript thing.

Here is a link with further explanation:

[How to use promises in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

[How to use AXIOS with promise](https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage)